# Identify a book series, where order fights against chaos and they travel back in time

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, powers

I'm trying to remember a book series I read in the mid-2000s. I've tried to remember as much as possible, some of the details might be incorrect. The book series is for young adults/teens and I think the author was Australian.

In the series, some people are born with superpowers and are recruited into the forces of the Babylonian god of Order (good guys), or the Babylonian god of Chaos (bad guys). The forces of Chaos typically travel back in time to alter an event (and thus make the present more chaotic), and the forces of Order have to travel back as well, identify the Chaos agents and stop them from changing history.

The two main characters were a boy (I think his superpowers include telekenisis) and girl at the same high school, in a town with a name similar to Angel Falls or Victoria Springs. Later on in the series a second boy is introduced who also attends the same school, but he is fighting for the bad guys. At the beginning of the first book the story centres on the boy and his mentor, a ~200 year old guy with purple eyes/hair (his superpower is not ageing). He operates from an ancient base underneath a large mountain.

Plot points include the main characters discovering their powers and learning how to use them, getting ingratieted into the order group and delving into the mountain in some sort of trial/ritual.

Can you identify this story?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is the [Guardians of Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Guardians_of_Time) trilogy by Australian author [Marianne Curley](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marianne_Curley).

[Goodreads](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1034516.The_Named) has this description of *The Named* (2002), the first in the series:

> Ethan lives a secret life as a Guardian of the Named. Under the guidance of Arkarian, his mentor, and with the help of Isabel, his unlikely but highly capable apprentice, Ethan has become a valued member of this other-worldly corps. As the only defense against the evil Order of Chaos, the Named travel through time to prevent the Order from altering history and thereby gaining power in the present and the future.
>
> As the threat from the Order intensifies, secrets of the past are revealed and villains and heroes are exposed. This gripping fantasy is set in modern times, but is infused with intrigue from the past, super-natural characters and surprising plot twists. Curley has written a winner through to the end.

Comment: Yes. This is the one! Although confusingly it is "The Guard vs The Order of Chaos" rather than "Order vs Chaos"...